# Calculating power for Decimals in Python

Tags: python

I want to calculate power for `Decimal` in Python like:

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal.power(2,2)
```

Above should return me as `Decimal('2)`

How can I calculate power for `Decimals`?

EDIT:
This is what i did

```
y = Decimal('10')**(x-deci_x+Decimal(str(n))-Decimal('1'))
```

x,deci_x are of decimal type

but above expression is throwing error as:

```
decimal.InvalidOperation: x ** (non-integer)
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ha.py", line 28, in ?
    first_k_1=first_k(2,n-1,k)
  File "ha.py", line 18, in first_k
    y = Decimal('10')**(x-deci_x+Decimal(str(n))-Decimal('1'))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/decimal.py", line 1709, in __pow__
    return context._raise_error(InvalidOperation, 'x ** (non-integer)')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/decimal.py", line 2267, in _raise_error
    raise error, explanation
```

Comment: @ Mayank Jain you can't use `**` with non-integer values. Have a look at the solution below using the `pow` function from the `math` module.

Comment: @danodonovan - But problem is if i apply pow then my precision would be reduced...

Comment: In python 3.4, `Decimal` has a `power` function

Answer (score 12):

You can calculate power using `**`:

```
2**3  # yields 8

a = Decimal(2)
a**2  # yields Decimal(4)
```

Following your update, seems okay for me:

```
>>> x = Decimal(2)
>>> deci_x = Decimal(1)
>>> n=4
>>> y = Decimal('10')**(x-deci_x+Decimal(str(n))-Decimal('1'))
>>> y
Decimal('10000')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the power operator `**` with Decimal...

```
print(Decimal(2)**Decimal(2)) # 4
```

*Edit, followup to your question*

You don't need to parse stings to Decimal()...

```
from decimal import Decimal
x, deci_x, n = Decimal(2), Decimal(3), 4
y = Decimal(10)**(x-deci_x+Decimal(n)-Decimal(1))
print(y) # 100
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python >= 3.4 as `Decimal` has a [`power` function](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context.power).

```
>>> decimal.power(Decimal('2'), Decimal('2.5'))
```

Or simply using the `math` module;

```
from math import pow
pow(2, 2)
```

using decimals

```
>>> pow(Decimal('2'), Decimal('2'))
```

and non-integer decimals will also work

```
>>> pow(Decimal('2'), Decimal('2.5'))
```

Comment: `>>> timeit.timeit("pow(a,b)",setup="from math import pow; from decimal import Decimal; a,b = Decimal('10'), Decimal('123')",number=1000)
0.009331226348876953`
That's **0.0093 for pow**

`>>> timeit.timeit("a**b",setup="from math import pow; from decimal import Decimal; a,b = Decimal('10'), Decimal('123')",number=1000)
0.031520843505859375`
That's **0.0315* for \*\***

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.4.6 does not support non-integer powers for Decimals. From the `__pow__` method in `decimal.py`:

```
def __pow__(self, n, modulo = None, context=None):
    #[snip]
    if not n._isinteger():
        return context._raise_error(InvalidOperation, 'x ** (non-integer)')
```

if `x-deci_x+Decimal(str(n))-Decimal('1')` is always an integer, convert it into the integer type before using it as an exponent. If you need the exponent to be a non-integer, consider upgrading to a more recent version of Python.